# wp_dropdown_categories and custom attribute

Tags: functions, customization

I'm using this jQuery plugin to handle select element on my site: [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Unfortunately, I can't found any option which allow me add a custom attribute to the select element, for e.g:

I want my dropdown look like this:

```
<select class="dropdown" data-live-search="true">
...
</select>
```

Is there any chance for me?

Comment: I don't think you can with `wp_dropdown_categories` but why not add the attribute at runtime using JavaScript before initiating the `bootstrap-select`

Comment: Either create your own `select` and `option` elements, or add the attribute per JavaScript. There is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

The only filter available is `wp_dropdown_cats`, which allows you to filter the entire HTML `select` string and that means trying to string-match markup. That is always a bit questionable. Still...

```
function dropdown_data_attr_wpse_213033($output){
  return str_replace('<select','<select data-live-search="true"',$output);
}
add_filter('wp_dropdown_cats','dropdown_data_attr_wpse_213033');
wp_dropdown_categories(); // test
```